# Customize app bar like gmail app bar design in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I customize an app bar with a round edge like the gmail app bar design? [Here is a screen shot of the gmail app bar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E05SH.jpg)

Comment: try to use a `card` rather than an `AppBar` widget.

Comment: Get an error like type 'Card' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'

Answer (score 1):

Use this package: [floating_search_bar](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/floating_search_bar)

[Here's](https://github.com/AppleEducate/gmail_clone) the complete example of gmail app.